# docker snap: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: snap, docker

I added the docker snap package to my Ubuntu 16.04 machine

```
sudo snap install docker
```

Now, when I try to use it, I get the following error...

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Comment: I didn't find any of thes solutions terribly helpful and ended up resort to installing via `apt` instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Due to confinement issues in the evolving snappy model, Docker is not full flavored by default ([see the discussion on the Snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-declaration-request-for-docker-snap/394)).

To get some helpful instructions on how to work around (i.e. break) the confinement model until the proper fix is in place. You can simply check the Docker help application packaged in the snap.

```
$ docker.help
Docker snap: Docker Linux container runtime.

Due to the confinement issues on snappy, it requires some manual setup to make docker-snap works on your machine.
We'll take you through the steps needed to set up docker snap work for you on ubuntu core and ubuntu classic.

On Ubuntu classic, before installing the docker snap, 
please run the following command to add the login user into docker group.
    sudo addgroup --system docker
    sudo adduser $USER docker
    newgrp docker

On Ubuntu Core 16, after installing the docker snap from store,
Firstly, you need to connect the two interfaces as they're not auto-connected by default.
    sudo snap connect docker:account-control :account-control
    sudo snap connect docker:home :home

Secondly, reload the snap and allows the user to login to the new group "docker-snap".
    snap disable docker
    snap enable  docker
    newgrp docker-snap

Then have fun with docker in snappy.
```

The last command fails...

```
$ newgrp docker-snap
newgrp: group 'docker-snap' does not exist
```

However, I did not notice any negative impact based on the failure, and Docker now functions as I would expect.

Comment: Aligning with the above, you can read the [instructions for using the Ubuntu snap version of docker as a regular user](https://snapcraft.io/docker) over on snapcraft (see the commands beneath the "Running Docker as normal user" heading).

Comment: Note: docker.help does not provide the same set of instructions as above, however 'sudo snap enable|disable docker' commands from above were the missing steps I needed.

Answer (score 12):

Use `snap start docker` to activate the service. It might need root permissions.

Comment: didn't help: ``Cannot connect to the Docker daemon``

Comment: @maslick `sudo snap start docker`

Answer (score 6):

If ...

```
sudo snap start docker
```

... does not help, try to remove and reinstall docker

```
sudo snap remove docker --purge
```

this also will delete images, containers and stuff docker has created

```
sudo snap install docker
```

Comment: Bravo!! All above solutions failed, and only this one works for me, when I want to run `docker images` without sudo! thanks!

Comment: `this also will delete images, containers and stuff docker has created`. What about volumes?

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by running:

```
sudo snap start docker
```

then running `sudo` on subsequent docker commands:

```
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

Without the `sudo` on the subsequent docker commands, the `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon` error persists.

Comment: Unless there's another issue here, if you create a group called `docker` and add your account to it, docker will use that group for its socket so you can use it without sudo. `groupadd docker && usermod -a -G docker username && reboot`.

Comment: I dunno, seems like a good idea to use `sudo` -- or at least a special user.